# FIWARE - Are any request headers forwarded to Orion Context Provider?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

[Context Broker with Context Provider](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/QueryContextWithContextProvider.png)

Queries (e.g. `GET /v2/entities?q=temperature>40`) from the ContextConsumers aren't sent to the ContextProvider: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2282

I am examining the following alternative:

- Create a web application and place it between the ContextBroker and the ContextProvider.
- The payload of `POST /v2/registrations` contains the lines below:

```json
  "provider": {
    "http": {
      "url": "URL of the web app"
    }
  }
```

- The request header of `GET /v2/entities` from a ContextConsumer includes query information if the ContextConsumer wants a filtered response.
- The web app relays requests and responses from/to the ContextBroker to/from the ContextProvider.
- The web app filters the responses from the ContextProvider to the ContextBroker when the
  ContextConsumers put query information in their request headers.

Could anyone let me know if any request headers are forwarded to a ContextProvider by a ContextBroker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the request headers that are being forwarded are:

- fiware-correlator
- fiware-service
- fiware-servicepath
- x-auth-token

For more detail, I'd recommend to have a look to the [`httpSendRequest()` function implementation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/src/lib/rest/httpRequestSend.cpp) in the Orion Context Broker code.

Comment: Thank you for your replay again. 
I will check the source code.